# Elegant Objects. Encapsulating LINQ query into IEnumerable<> implemented class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, domain-driven-design

***Hi, considering such code to be more OOD-like than a static method with LINQ query.***

*The idea came from [Yegor Bugayenko](https://github.com/yegor256) speeches and topics.*

***Is my interpretation correct?***

**Interested in the second opinion from .NET community for this approach.**

*What disadvantages this code might have?*

For sure Functional approach might be shorter, but what about reuse/test/read abilities?

****Functional:****

```
private static IEnumerable<Entity> FilterEntities(IEnumerable<Entity> entities) =>
    entities.Where(x => x.Field == value); // some robust filtering and mapping
```

****OOP:****

```
public class FilteredEntities : IEnumerable<Entity>
{
        private readonly IEnumerable<Entity> _entities;

        public FilteredEntities(IEnumerable<Entity> entities)
        {
            _entities = entities.Where(x => x.Field == value); // some robust filtering and mapping
        }

        public IEnumerator<Entity> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _entities.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
}
```

Appreciate critics/suggestions/alternatives.

UPD:
As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg) suggested for this case [Specification pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) which seems to be a better alternative.

Comment: This question seems to be a better fit at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do here really, though I would suggest implementing `IEnumerable` is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @DavidG, for instance, I have some complex LINQ filtering and mapping that I may use in different places, so the idea is to encapsulate some shared business logic to use it across multiple classes or methods. Would you rather move this to a static class with an extension methods?

Comment: Like I said, it all depends. You may want to look at the specification pattern though, I've used that for complex filtering scenarios before.

Comment: @DavidG, thanks for the suggestion. Never heard of this pattern before.